# tableofcontents unbold

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, bold, tocloft

[image]

I hope default condition - unbold - all words and numbers.

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\recommand{secfont}{nomarl}
```

Answer (score 4):

Update the following macros to not have `\bfseries` in them: `\cfttoctitlefont`, `\cftsecfont`, and `\cftsecpagefont`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\normalfont\Large}% Remove \bfseries from ToC title
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{}% Remove \bfseries from section titles in ToC
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{}% Remove \bfseries from section titles' page in ToC

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\section{Problem 1}

\section{Problem 2}

\section{Problem 3}

\end{document}
```

Another quick-fix would be to set `\bfseries` to be equivalent to `\mdseries` (or nothing) within a group that has a limit scope around the ToC only:

```
{\let\bfseries\mdseries% ...or \let\bfseries\relax
\tableofcontents
}
```

But this may affect content within the headers/footers as well.

Comment: Thank you !!! but `contents` <- not center :)

Comment: @JoB: Strange... you didn't ask about though. I guess my crystal ball wasn't with me at the time. Use `\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}[1]{\hfill\normalfont\Large#1\hfill\mbox{}}`

Comment: i`m sorry,,, i crying

Comment: @JoB: Don't cry. ;) However, if this answered your question, consider accepting it as such. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://goo.gl/hzFkJ)